# ValueError: could not convert string to float 'jpg' Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/kot/cat.1633.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array('cat.1633.jpg')
```

I get this error:

```
File "<string>", line 566, in run_nodebug
File "C:\Users\Nixid\Desktop\ta.py", line 37, in <module>
test_image = image.img_to_array('cat.1633.jpg')
File "C:\Users\Nixid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 423, in img_to_array
x = np.asarray(img, dtype=backend.floatx())
File "C:\Users\Nixid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'cat.1633.jpg'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Try test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image) instead of test_image = image.img_to_array('cat.1633.jpg')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kera's [`img_to_array()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/img_to_array) method takes a [`PIL.Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) instance (as returned by [`load_img()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img)) as its parameter, not the name of a file. So you will need to pass it the `test_image` you loaded in the first line:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

test_image = image.load_img('dataset/kot/cat.1633.jpg', target_size=(64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
```

Hth :)
dtk

PS As commented above, it's generally a good idea to paste the whole error message, including a [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace), as - with some practice - that makes it much easier to understand what's going on. Also, showing the imports that are required to quickly reproduce the problem will make debugging way nicer